# VB.NET Azure Functions — what does the Microsoft.CSharp assembly do?

Tags: c#, vb.net, azure, azure-functions

I've been able to publish and consume an Azure Function in pure VB.NET, with no C# wrapper class. (For the interested, the how-to can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/475).)

During publish, however, this warning is issued:

> Could not evaluate 'Microsoft.CSharp.dll' for extension metadata. Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Obviously, this occurs because I'm publishing from a VB.NET project and the assembly is never referenced/loaded there.

But the omission seems to have no effect on the functionality of the code. It runs fine and returns the expected result.

My question is this: what role does the assembly play in an Azure Function?

We find this on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/):

> Provides support for compilation and code generation, including dynamic, using the C# language

Well and good, but we're not doing any of that here.

Since the function runs successfully, would I be correct in a guess that the assembly is required only as an interpreter for a C# Script Azure Function?

Basically I'm trying to assess whether I'm production-ready with this approach, despite the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when publishing an Azure Function we look for every binary in an assembly, and some platforms can't evaluate certain assemblies (e.g. A VB.NET platform cannot evaluate a CSharp assembly).

This warning is logged as an FYI, but its nothing to be concerned about.

Here is a link to GitHub with an answer that confirms this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4856#issuecomment-526183588

Answer (score 1):

One of your dependencies might depend on it. You should include it.

Comment: Perfect. I'll do so. Thank you. (Not sure why I didn't see that myself.)

Comment: Hm... just tried, and I encountered the same warning in Visual Studio, but at design time. Also, the warning persists even after I remove the reference. Any ideas? The new Standard/Core project architectures are new to me and are still a bit obscure.

Comment: @InteXX how did you reference it?

Comment: I added it from NuGet. Also, the version called for in the warning doesn't exist as a published package.

Comment: @InteXX the vb.net support for .net core is spotty at best. why not use c# from the getgo?

Comment: As a wrapper, yes, I could always do so. But I'm trying to reduce as much design overhead as I can get away with. (I've 20 yrs exp. at VB, and a mere fraction of that at C#.) I suppose I'm in uncharted territory with this.

Comment: @InteXX vb.net is not really different from c#, you just have to get used to the sintaxis, the rest (libraries, frameworks, classes and functions) are the same

Comment: @Bloodday ~ Thank you. If I end up using wrapper classes, I'll use your advice as a source of solace and comfort :-)